# Dell 9550 Crashes while on battery - Win 10

Tags: windows-10, laptop, crash, battery, dell-xps

Been trying to solve this forever.  Dell 9550 (XPS 15) - consistently crashes after 20-60 minutes while on battery power (fine on AC).  The way the crash works is this: first the mouse/trackpad and keyboard lock up, then a minute or so later the screen freezes.  So during that minute video/animations continue to play.

Tried playing with the BIOS, disabling c-states, etc.  Also switched to high-performance mode in Win 10, changed all settings to be the same as AC, same issue.

Any idea what it could be?  I'm hoping the pattern of the crash reveals something about what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Swap batteries if one is available. If the problem goes away, the old battery may have something in the logic circuitry that opens up when it heats and expands.

Comment: I'll try, but don't think overheating is the case, because after it restarts the time until the next crash is pretty much the same...